# Problems with serilog.settings.appsettings and file rollover interval

Tags: serilog

I am using SeriLog for logging in my IdentityServer3-based authentication service. I just replaced the serilog.sinks.literate plug in with the serilog.sinks.file plug in in order to get the rolling file capability offered by the File plug in. When I use the File plug in with the following configuration code in Startup.cs, it works as I expect. (I'm only using the RolloverInterval.Minute for testing. I'll switch to RolloverInterval.Day when I deploy the code.)

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.File("E:\\Site\\AuthSvc\\Trace.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute, retainedFileCountLimit: 10)
.CreateLogger();
```

As I said, that works as expected, creating a new file each minute.

Now I'm trying to use the serilog.settings.appsettings plug in to manage all of that configuration in appSettings instead of in code. So I changed the above code to:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.AppSettings()
.CreateLogger();
```

And I included the following in my web.config appSettings:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
<add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="E:\Site\AuthSvc\Trace.log"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="RollingInterval.Minute"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10"/>
```

When I run the service with the above configuration, I get the error message "Requested value 'RollingInterval.Minute' was not found." Similar error occurs with any RollingInterval value.

If I remove the last two appSettings, it works fine. Am I doing something wrong or does the appSettings plug in not support the rolling file features of the File sink plug in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is documented (I'll check), but when setting the value for enums via `Serilog.Settings.AppSettings` you only specify the enum member name, without the name of the enum.

e.g. instead of

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="RollingInterval.Minute"/>
```

**use**

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Minute"/>
```

Comment: I've added some docs: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings/pull/32

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in a appsettings.json file:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\Temp\\log-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyService"
    }
  }
```